# Context free Grammar and regular set

Tags: regular-languages, context-free

I read a question and I don't understand it, is the set consisting of: production rules of Grammars that are CFGs, itself a regular set? The only thing I know is that the type 3 is under the type 2 in CNF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A context-free grammar is just a string such as "$A\to 0A0\mid 1A1\mid 0\mid 1$".  Forget for the moment that such a string happens to define a language (in this case, the set of all odd-length binary palindromes) and focus on the fact that it's a string over some alphabet.

Now, let $L$ be the set of strings that are regular grammars.  A set of strings is a language.  The question is asking if $L$ is a regular language.

Comment: does it ask of a language that is both type 3 and type 2?

Comment: No. Forget the fact that a CFG has some kind of a meaning. Imagine somebody gives you a string of characters and says, "Is that a context-free grammar?" So, for the string "$A\to 0A0\mid1A1\mid0\mid1", you should answer "yes" and for the string "Computer Science Stack Exchange", you should answer "no". The question is asking if you can use a DFA to decide whether a string is a context-free grammar.

Comment: you mean if it is regular grammar then we can say it is CFG? so we can use DFA to decide that the language is CFG, and the answer of the question is yes because every regular grammar is CFG. Right?

Comment: but the palindromes is not regular language, right? how we can use DFA to determine this?

Comment: You're just trying to determine whether a given string is a CFG or not. If the string is a CFG, it doesn't matter what language it describes. Just is that string a grammar or isn't it?

Comment: The question is about the set production rules. are they regular set? so the set should have a production rules for regular set to be regular and CFL,Right? so you mean by using DFA we can see it is a production rules for a grammar. This question is really vague.

Comment: @Loura The question isn't vague at all but I can't think of any more ways to explain it.